# My skin is hard

Tags: riddle

> In hair, I am all dressed
>   My flesh as well, appreciated
>   Even though I am not an animal
>   I produce milk for you all

Can you guess what I am?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you a

> Coconut?

In hair, I am all dressed

> They are hairy-ish

My flesh as well, appreciated

> Coconut flesh can be made into shreds.

Eventhough, I am not an animal

> Not an animal.

I produce milk for you all

> Coconut Milk!

Regarding the title

> They are hard to break open because of their skin.

Answer (score 9):

You are

> a coconut.

In hair, I am all dressed

> The outer shell of a coconut is adorned with what could be described as "hairy" fibres.

My flesh as well, appreciated

> The white flesh within the coconut can be eaten.

Even though, I am not an animal

> It's a coconut.

I produce milk for you all

> Coconuts contain milk.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other posts got it but another answer might be:

Are you a

> Soybean plant?

In hair, I am all dressed

> The pods have a sort of hair on them

My flesh as well, appreciated

> Soybeans are used in a lot of things

Eventhough, I am not an animal

> It is a plant

I produce milk for you all

> Soy milk

Regarding the title

> They aren't really hard, but compared to some fruits and stuff I guess it would be a hard skin?